# joomla site with regional differences

Tags: joomla, region

I have a Joomla site which is based in one country (US). We've been tasked to create a UK/GB version of the site which has it's own domain, but shares the same common pages/posts/backend. About 75% of the pages are the same on both versions but there will be a few sections (like About and Contact) where they are different to account for regional differences.

Example

US site (www.example.com) has

- Home About Services Contact UK Site (www.example.co.uk) has 3 pages
  (2 different, 1 the same)
- Home (The same as US, but the URL should be www.example.co.uk) About
  (Different content, the URL should be www.example.co.uk/about)
  Services (The same as US, but URL should be
  www.example.co.uk/services) Contact (Different content, the URL
  should be www.example.co.uk/contact)

How do I go about setting up the UK/GB version of the site which use the same backend and most of the same content from the base site, but has a few page differences and different domain?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should somehow rely on the multilingual feature of Joomla! (http://multilingual-joomla-demo.cloudaccess.net/multi-lingual-steps-by-steps.html)

Define for example languages for US / UK. Pages that are identical for both, just leave the language setting to "All".

For the rest specify the language.

Hope this helps.